# How to delete rows after a disease has been detected (Right censoring)

Tags: r, detection, delete-row, cox-regression

I am trying to right censor data but am having trouble making the code work. I want the code to delete all the observations AFTER the first "1". Meaning I do not want to delete that first line of detection. I am getting so close but either getting errors or deleting to little/much. Could you please assist me.

My closest attempt:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% group_by(record_id) %>% filter(if(1 %in% te_yn) row_number() == 1: (which(te_yn == 1) -1) else TRUE)
```

Data used:

```
est <- structure(list(record_id = c(120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 
                             120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 
                             120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 
                             120321, 120322, 120322, 120322, 120322, 120322, 120322, 120322, 
                             120322, 120322, 120322), day_count = c(579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 
                                                                    584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 
                                                                    597, 598, 599, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588
                             ), day_count_stop = c(580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 
                                                   588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 
                                                   580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 586, 587, 588, 589, 590), te_yn = c(0, 
                                                                                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cumulatively sum `te_yn`, and filter out values that are greater than one. As you want to keep the first `1`, we also use the `dplyr::lag` function.

```
est %>% filter(lag(cumsum(te_yn), default = 0) < 1)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 13 × 4
   record_id day_count day_count_stop te_yn
       <dbl>     <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl>
 1    120321       579            580     0
 2    120321       580            581     0
 3    120321       581            582     0
 4    120321       582            583     0
 5    120321       583            584     0
 6    120321       584            585     0
 7    120321       585            586     0
 8    120321       586            587     0
 9    120321       587            588     0
10    120321       588            589     0
11    120321       589            590     0
12    120321       590            591     0
13    120321       591            592     1
```

Comment: You should include a `group_by` call first to make sure data for each group is returned. i.e. `est %>% group_by(record_id) %>% filter(lag(cumsum(te_yn), default = 0) < 1)`

Answer (score 0):

We can do it with `cumsum`:

```
library(dplyr) #> 1.1.0

est %>% 
  filter(!cumsum(te_yn) > 0, .by=record_id)

   record_id day_count day_count_stop te_yn
       <dbl>     <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl>
 1    120321       579            580     0
 2    120321       580            581     0
 3    120321       581            582     0
 4    120321       582            583     0
 5    120321       583            584     0
 6    120321       584            585     0
 7    120321       585            586     0
 8    120321       586            587     0
 9    120321       587            588     0
10    120321       588            589     0
11    120321       589            590     0
12    120321       590            591     0
13    120322       579            580     0
14    120322       580            581     0
15    120322       581            582     0
16    120322       582            583     0
17    120322       583            584     0
```